# jdbc cannot connect to mysql server

Tags: jdbc, nullpointerexception

```
package com.company.fyp.fyp;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ConnectDataBase {

    Connection con;
    String dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String dbPath = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "test_android";
    String user = "admin";
    String pdw = "admin";

    void ConnectDatabase(){

        try{

            Class.forName(dbDriver).newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath + dbName , user, pdw);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public Connection getCon(){
        return con;
    }

}
```

I checked that con is null. I think my dataname name ,user, pdw are all correct. Wondering if I need to change some of xampp mysql server settings. What is the problem.

Comment: Looks like you fixed the code issues..Are you getting an exception? If so, put it here

Answer (score 0):

Your connect string is incorrect.
It should be of the form

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://{server}:{port}/{dbName}";
```

Right now you are appending the port at the end. Also there is a `/` at the end of dbPath. See below.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dbName;
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pdw);
```

Also make sure the `mysql-connector` jar is in the classpath. You can download the library from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j)

Comment: Do you have the mysql-connector jar? Do you see any exception? Print the stack trace instead of `System.err.println("Error")`

Comment: I got my jar file in libs file. is that the right place?  and if I continue to use the connection object, the nullpointerexception comes out

Comment: I dont see the that print statement in logcat. But if(con==null)Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to connect to server!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); shows con is null

Comment: Looks like you are using this inside of Android device !! Exposing your database over RESTful services would be a better approach.  My guess is in your case, the connection object is being garbage collected. Create an instance variable for `Connection` in your MainActivity and then access it where required.